Can std::recursive_mutex ever cause a deadlock?
I know if I lock std::mutex twice in one thread, it will cause a deadlock.
So, I globally replaced std::mutex with std::recursive_mutex.
Does only using std::recursive_mutex mean I will never encounter a deadlock?
Is there any potential problem with that (except for it being slightly slower) ?

This is related to Will recursive_mutex deadlock when locked by 2 threads?, but that question is about the case where there is only one mutex, so not a dupe.

recursive_mutex only solves the problem when the potential deadlock is caused by 1 thread that needs access to 1 protected resource.
You can still encounter a deadlock using a recursive_mutex, if more than one resource is involved.
Consider the following scenario involving 2 threads that need exclusive access to 2 resources (each protected by a mutex):

ThreadA locks RecursiveMutexA to gain access to ResourceA.
ThreadB locks RecursiveMutexB to gain access to ResourceB.
ThreadA tries to lock RecursiveMutexB to gain access to ResourceB - and deadlocks.
ThreadB tries to lock RecursiveMutexA to gain access to ResourceA - and deadlocks.

The classical textbook solution to this scenario is that all threads must lock the mutexes at the same order.
Alternatively, if applicable in your case, you can use std::lock to lock multiple locks at once.
The later approach can be much faster, as shown in this article by Howard Hinnant: Dining Philosophers Rebooted.

Or, if the locks can be locked at the same place in the code, use std::lock.  This paper shows that std::lock can be significantly faster than locking in order.

@HowardHinnant thanks, added this info to my answer.

Different orders or conditions can be your enemy. Consider the following (I used namespace std to declutter, though it's generally not best practice):
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
recursive_mutex firstOne, secondOne;

void threadingOne() {
    lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock1(firstOne);

    //pretend stuff happens
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

    lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock2(secondOne);
}

void threadingTwo() {
    lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock2(secondOne);

    //this is stuff happening
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

    lock_guard<recursive_mutex> lock1(firstOne);
}

int main() {
    thread threadOne(threadingOne);
    thread threadTwo(threadingTwo);
    threadOne.join();
    threadTwo.join();

    cout << "This is not something you will see ever\n";
    return 0;
}



Replacing std::mutex with std::recursive_mutex helps avoid deadlocks from a thread locking itself.
It's not a guaranteed fix. Deadlocks can still happen with wrong locking order or external resource dependencies.
Use std::recursive_mutex only when truly needed for recursive locking. Consider alternatives otherwise.
